# Encoding a h264 video from png images... in JAVA

Tags: java, h.264

Is there a freely available jar file somewhere that can help me to convert a set of png files to an .avi file?

Just looking for a codec that is compatible with java that does not require the antiquated JMF.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

JCodec ( http://jcodec.org) is what you are looking for. It's an open source pure java video codec library. It doesn't support AVI at the moment but IMHO MP4 format is better suited for H.264 anyway.

In case you decide to go with JCodec, here's a sample class you can use:

```
public class SequenceEncoder {
    private SeekableByteChannel ch;
    private Picture toEncode;
    private RgbToYuv420 transform;
    private H264Encoder encoder;
    private ArrayList<ByteBuffer> spsList;
    private ArrayList<ByteBuffer> ppsList;
    private CompressedTrack outTrack;
    private ByteBuffer _out;
    private int frameNo;
    private MP4Muxer muxer;

    public SequenceEncoder(File out) throws IOException {
        this.ch = NIOUtils.writableFileChannel(out);

        // Transform to convert between RGB and YUV
        transform = new RgbToYuv420(0, 0);

        // Muxer that will store the encoded frames
        muxer = new MP4Muxer(ch, Brand.MP4);

        // Add video track to muxer
        outTrack = muxer.addTrackForCompressed(TrackType.VIDEO, 25);

        // Allocate a buffer big enough to hold output frames
        _out = ByteBuffer.allocate(1920 * 1080 * 6);

        // Create an instance of encoder
        encoder = new H264Encoder();

        // Encoder extra data ( SPS, PPS ) to be stored in a special place of
        // MP4
        spsList = new ArrayList<ByteBuffer>();
        ppsList = new ArrayList<ByteBuffer>();

    }

    public void encodeImage(BufferedImage bi) throws IOException {
        if (toEncode == null) {
            toEncode = Picture.create(bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight(), ColorSpace.YUV420);
        }

        // Perform conversion
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            Arrays.fill(toEncode.getData()[i], 0);
        transform.transform(AWTUtil.fromBufferedImage(bi), toEncode);

        // Encode image into H.264 frame, the result is stored in '_out' buffer
        _out.clear();
        ByteBuffer result = encoder.encodeFrame(_out, toEncode);

        // Based on the frame above form correct MP4 packet
        spsList.clear();
        ppsList.clear();
        H264Utils.encodeMOVPacket(result, spsList, ppsList);

        // Add packet to video track
        outTrack.addFrame(new MP4Packet(result, frameNo, 25, 1, frameNo, true, null, frameNo, 0));

        frameNo++;
    }

    public void finish() throws IOException {
        // Push saved SPS/PPS to a special storage in MP4
        outTrack.addSampleEntry(H264Utils.createMOVSampleEntry(spsList, ppsList));

        // Write MP4 header and finalize recording
        muxer.writeHeader();
        NIOUtils.closeQuietly(ch);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SequenceEncoder encoder = new SequenceEncoder(new File("video.mp4"));
        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
            BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new File(String.format("folder/img%08d.png", i)));
            encoder.encodeImage(bi);
        }
        encoder.finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just recommend using SequenceEncoder, rather than pasting the file's contents? In any case, it appears that jcodec 1.6 has some issues: encoding a short sequence of bufferedimages doesn't yield a video that will play, though it seems to get the resolution right and show a preview image.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see poor java solution, but You can try xuggler with it's ffmpeg warper.